# Judge one dimensional ndarray exist in two dimensional ndarray [numpy]

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to know how to judge whether a specific one dimensional ndarray exist in a specific two dimensional ndarray in numpy.

The code like:

```py
a=np.array([[1,3],[2,4]])
b=np.array([1,3])
c=np.array([1,2])
d=np.array([1,5])
e=np.array([5])
print(b in a, c in a, d in a, e in a)
```

The output is `True True True False`,

but i hope the result is `True False False False`, like `list` in Python:

```py
a=[[1,3],[2,4]]
b=[1,3]
c=[1,2]
d=[1,5]
e=[5]
print(b in a, c in a, d in a, e in a)
```

This requirement is a key part of the operation in my code. Any efficient implementation is welcome.

Comment: `(subarr == arr).all(-1).any()`

Comment: @MechanicPig It works and thanks very much. Also, is this the best implementation of the requirement?